# CRM 2011 Report in IFRAME not accessible through javascript

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to access report data and it's param using java script when report gets displayed inside IFRAME on the CRM form.

Althought Iframe is accessible and if it contains html then html will be accessible but does it allow to access report in Iframe ?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your effort.

Comment: Hi Arun, 
I tried to access the report's components using it's id, even tried to access div using id but it return null whereas I got everywhere that html component is accessible using ID.

So, I asked the same that using getElementById is working in html, does it work in report or report is displayed in separate url in Iframe so it is not accessible ? This is my question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access report inside iframe below is how we have done it. We have CRM 2013 on-premise setup.

We use custom JavaScript code to hide report ribbon on report inside `CRM Dashboard` inside iframe.

1. On CRM `Dashboard` or `form` where you have the report which you want to access through `JavaScript`, add an html Web Resource which will have the following code.

   ```
   function onBodyLoad(){
   var contentIFrame0= window.top.document.getElementById('contentIFrame0')
   if(contentIFrame0)
    {
        var dashboardFrame=contentIFrame0.contentDocument.frames["dashboardFrame"];
        if (dashboardFrame!= undefined) {
            var elem = mainFrame.document.frames["yourReportIframe"];
            if (elem != undefined && elem.document.getElementById("compatibilityNotification")!=undefined) {
               elem.document.getElementById("compatibilityNotification").style.display = "none";;
               elem.document.getElementById("crmMenuBar").style.display = "none";
             }
        else {
            setTimeout(onBodyLoad, 3000);
        }
    }
   }
   ```

Please note that the above code snippet is specifically for `CRM Dashboards`, you should change it to your specific needs for CRM forms.